# Highcharts 'Stacked' graph with chart type as 'area' to be smoother

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a requirement to have Stacked graph with chart type area and not areaspline. But I don't want the tips of graph to be pointed and rather a bit smoother.

Is it possible with API?

Comment: No, there is no setting to accomplish this. You would have to alter the path of the line itself - you would essentially need to make this a spline, just with different curve formulas.  Which doesn't seem to really make sense from a data presentation standpoint.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the reply.